# masm directive option prologue:none has no effect

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, syntax, masm, masm64

I'm learning how to use masm using MS's official docs, but there's almost nothing written on the `option` directive (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/option-masm?view=msvc-170). It was used in the standard library implementation of `memcpy` where it seems to work properly

my code:

```
title entry - general purpose testing ground for asm operations
include ksamd64.inc
        subttl  "entry"

    NESTED_ENTRY entry, _TEXT
    option PROLOGUE:NONE, EPILOGUE:NONE
;       error here: "A2220 Missing .ENDPROLOGUE"
        cvtpi2ps xmm0, qword ptr[rcx]
        rsqrtps xmm1, xmm0
        movaps xmmword ptr[rcx], xmm1
    
        cvtpi2ps xmm0, qword ptr[rcx+8]
        rsqrtps xmm1, xmm0
        movups xmmword ptr[rcx+8], xmm1
    .beginepilog
        ret
    NESTED_END entry, _TEXT
end
```

Comment: Separate from MASM shenanigans and inconveniences, it's probably faster to convert and rsqrt 4 floats at once instead of 2, with `cvtdq2ps xmm0, [rcx]` (aligned 16-byte load allows folding a memory source operand instead of needing a separate `movups`) / `rsqrtps xmm0,xmm0` / `movaps [rcx], xmm0` (aligned 16-byte store is apparently ok).  If you actually need to store another 8 bytes of garbage starting at `[rcx+16]` like you're doing with the 16-byte `movups` store (from rsqrtps on whatever bit-patterns were in the high half of xmm0 on function entry), you can do that if you want.

Comment: `cvtdq2ps` writes the full destination with no false dependency, vs. `cvtpi2ps xmm, mm/m64` merging a new low qword into an XMM with a false dependency.  So even calling this in a loop, there's no downside to rsqrt in the same register.  (Of course, you should inline this into a loop instead of calling for every vector!  If you're using C or C++, intrinsics like `_mm_load_si128` (or `loadu` if maybe not aligned) / `_mm_cvtepi32_ps` will save you the trouble of hand-writing asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes that was just example code I put in, has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: I know, that's why I put them as comments instead of as an answer.  But clearly you got that code from somewhere, so I thought it would be helpful to point out that it's inefficient and possibly buggy.  If not you, then for future readers who see those instructions.  If you wanted a more minimal [mcve] without distractions, you could have trimmed it to just a `ret` as the function body, if that still reproduces the error message.

Comment: @PeterCordes its not a typo. that's how they want you to spell it for some reason. That's how its spelled in the msvc standard library implementation

Comment: Oh nvm, `.beginepilog` is "Begin Epilog / Epilogue".  That's totally normal, I'm just half asleep and was looking for any "prolog" directives, even if they were mis-placed not near the start of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed poorly documented, but is your code not mixing versions/environments?. I have dug up following info from *different corners of the web*.

About [`.ENDPROLOG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/dot-endprolog?view=msvc-170)

> Signals the end of the prologue declarations.
> It is an error to use any of the prologue declarations outside of the region between `PROC FRAME` and `.ENDPROLOG`.

---

About [`NESTED_ENTRY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms940763(v=msdn.10))

> A `NESTED_ENTRY` must have an associated `PROLOG_END` (SH-4) and `ENTRY_END` (SH-4).

About [`PROLOG_END`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms933593(v=msdn.10))

> This macro must appear following a `NESTED_ENTRY` (SH-4) or `LEAF_ENTRY` (SH-4) macro.
> It appears after the prolog area and before the matching `ENTRY_END` (SH-4) macro.

About [`ENTRY_END`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms933408(v=msdn.10))

> This macro ends the current routine specified by `NESTED_ENTRY` (SH-4) or `LEAF_ENTRY` (SH-4).
> Syntax `ENTRY_END[Name]`
> Name should be the same name used in the `NESTED_ENTRY` or `LEAF_ENTRY` macros.
> The `ENTRY_END` (SH-4) macro currently ignores Name.

---

You didn't use `PROLOG_END` and you wrote `NESTED_END` instead of `ENTRY_END`.

Why do you use the phrase `option PROLOGUE:NONE, EPILOGUE:NONE`? Perhaps simply remove it...

Comment: He mentioned that the options were used in Microsoft `memcpy` code. I did find something that may be related to that: https://gist.github.com/Const-me/3290266d2a5f51409eb813d39b28007c

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/option-masm?view=msvc-170 its listed as an option for the `OPTION` keyword. But it doesn't seem to do anything